# Can I put a method call in a component property at design time?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

Is it possible to put a placeholder for a method call in the property value of an object in the Object Inspector? I have a method that returns a string that I'd like to include as part of the connection-string properties of some TADOConnection objects. Changing the method's return value would alter what gets assigned to each of the connections as they're loaded from the DFM.

I'm using RAD Studio 2010.

Comment: You cannot expose actual methods in the Object Inspector, only data values (properties) and method pointers (events).  What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: I' ve got a method which returns a string.

I want to say put the method name in the connection string property of a TADOConnection, so I would only have to change the connection string in one place and it would change it for all of my connections

Comment: You could make a component where you add your `TADOConnection` objects. This custom component can then have a connection string property, and a list of `TADOConnection` objects to update when the connection string updates. This would really be simple if this is what you want.

Comment: yeah i could do that good idea. i also though i could just put it on an event. i was just wondering if there was a easy way :D

Comment: Well creating a component, with only that responsibility isn't really that much work, just tell me if you need any help. :)

Comment: Funny question. I suppose OP is accustomed to MS Access or similar.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cant. You can only have properties and events, but:

You can create a set method in you Connection property. This set method you search all forms and datamodules in you application and it will try to find an TADOConnection. When it finds one, it willl change its connection property. But this will only works in design time in the current form you put your component into, but it would work fine on runtime. Thats is not a pleasent solution, maybe you should try what @TommyA said on comments.

Comment: Also, it will works only in run time in forms that are already created.